# jQuery - Show Totals for Multiple Quantities Within Single Table Row

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple order form for wholesale use which shows totals updated in real time. The price stays the same per row. Here's where I'm at so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/80sgr4xr/

However right now whenever a new quantity is entered the total updates to show the total for that specific quantity. So if we add 1 - 0mg Honey Suckle and 2 - 3mg Honey Suckle the total should be 3 * 5 = 15. However right now it only calculates the last quantity entered - if that makes sense.

Any ideas how I can get this to function correctly? Here is my existing jQuery:

```
function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can streamline it a bit with:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function () {
    var rowSum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty').each(function () {
        if (this.value.length) rowSum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    })
    var rowPrice = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.price').text();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.sum').text((rowSum * rowPrice).toFixed(2))
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/80sgr4xr/2/)**

You weren't iterating over the inputs properly and were only holding onto the last value.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you mate. Any reason the main total in here doesn't seem to pickup any values within sum classes?

Comment: Not sure I understand.